# Перенос laravel на сервер

Tags: laravel

После переноса рабочего проекта с локалхост на сервер выводит ошибку

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Comment: Слишком мало информации для того, чтобы ответить на вопрос, пожалуйста посмотрите логи и дополните сообщениями из логов вопрос.

Comment: `composer install` не забыли, БД сконфигурили, `.env` перенесли, разрешешения на папки позволяют php писать в `/storage` и `/bootsrap/cache`?

Answer (score 1):

Для тех кто не может настроить Laravel 5. На данный момент есть такое решение:

1. В корневом каталоге создать .htaccess с таким содержимым:

   `RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
   RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [L]`
2. Далее в htaccess файле, который находиться в папке public закомментировать

   `Options -MultiViews`
3. После этого всё должно работать корректно.